# how to Insert Nested Json into ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-listfragment

I have a nested `JSON` like this

```
    {
error_no: "0",
    schedule: {
        depart: [
            {
            train_no: "U61",
            train_name: "ARS",
            from: "KLN",
            from_st_name: "Kuala Namu",
            to: "MDN",
            to_st_name: "Medan",
            ETD: "05:05",
            DD: "2013-12-28",
            ETA: "05:50",
            AD: "2013-12-28",
            Availability: [
                {
                sub_class: "A",
                seat: 172,
                class: "Eksekutif",
                adult_price: 80000,
                child_price: 80000
                }
            ]
            },
        ]
        return: [
            {
            train_no: "U62",
            train_name: "ARS",
            from: "MDN",
            from_st_name: "Medan",
            to: "KLN",
            to_st_name: "Kuala Namu",
            ETD: "04:00",
            DD: "2013-12-28",
            ETA: "04:37",
            AD: "2013-12-28",
            Availability: [
                {
                sub_class: "A",
                seat: 170,
                class: "Eksekutif",
                adult_price: 80000,
                child_price: 80000
                }
            ]
            },

        ]
    }

}
```

I want to show the `JSON` data into the listview like this
[Image](http://www.image-share.com/ipng-2376-145.html)

I already made the code like this on MSearchData.java

```
public class MSearchData {

    private String sessionId;
    private String trainNo,trainName,departDate,arrivalDate,etd,eta,totalSeat;
    private ArrayList subClass,seat,mainClass,adultPrice,childPrice,infantPrice;

    public MSearchData() {}

    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public String getTrainNo() {
        return trainNo;
    }

    public void setTrainNo(String trainNo) {
        this.trainNo = trainNo;
    }

    public String getTrainName() {
        return trainName;
    }

    public void setTrainName(String trainName) {
        this.trainName = trainName;
    }

    public String getDepartDate() {
        return departDate;
    }

    public void setDepartDate(String departDate) {
        this.departDate = departDate;
    }

    public String getArrivalDate() {
        return arrivalDate;
    }

    public void setArrivalDate(String arrivalDate) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
    }

    public String getEtd() {
        return etd;
    }

    public void setEtd(String etd) {
        this.etd = etd;
    }

    public String getEta() {
        return eta;
    }

    public void setEta(String eta) {
        this.eta = eta;
    }

    public String getTotalSeat() {
        return totalSeat;
    }

    public void setTotalSeat(String totalSeat) {
        this.totalSeat = totalSeat;
    }

    public ArrayList getSubClass() {
        return subClass;
    }

    public void setSubClass(ArrayList subClass) {
        this.subClass = subClass;
    }

    public ArrayList getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public void setSeat(ArrayList seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }

    public ArrayList getMainClass() {
        return mainClass;
    }

    public void setMainClass(ArrayList mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    public ArrayList getAdultPrice() {
        return adultPrice;
    }

    public void setAdultPrice(ArrayList adultPrice) {
        this.adultPrice = adultPrice;
    }

    public ArrayList getChildPrice() {
        return childPrice;
    }

    public void setChildPrice(ArrayList childPrice) {
        this.childPrice = childPrice;
    }

    public ArrayList getInfantPrice() {
        return infantPrice;
    }

    public void setInfantPrice(ArrayList infantPrice) {
        this.infantPrice = infantPrice;
    }
```

on SearchParser

```
    package com.inzpiretech.railink.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MSearchData {

    private String sessionId;
    private String trainNo,trainName,departDate,arrivalDate,etd,eta,totalSeat;
    private ArrayList subClass,seat,mainClass,adultPrice,childPrice,infantPrice;

    public MSearchData() {}

    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public String getTrainNo() {
        return trainNo;
    }

    public void setTrainNo(String trainNo) {
        this.trainNo = trainNo;
    }

    public String getTrainName() {
        return trainName;
    }

    public void setTrainName(String trainName) {
        this.trainName = trainName;
    }

    public String getDepartDate() {
        return departDate;
    }

    public void setDepartDate(String departDate) {
        this.departDate = departDate;
    }

    public String getArrivalDate() {
        return arrivalDate;
    }

    public void setArrivalDate(String arrivalDate) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
    }

    public String getEtd() {
        return etd;
    }

    public void setEtd(String etd) {
        this.etd = etd;
    }

    public String getEta() {
        return eta;
    }

    public void setEta(String eta) {
        this.eta = eta;
    }

    public String getTotalSeat() {
        return totalSeat;
    }

    public void setTotalSeat(String totalSeat) {
        this.totalSeat = totalSeat;
    }

    public ArrayList getSubClass() {
        return subClass;
    }

    public void setSubClass(ArrayList subClass) {
        this.subClass = subClass;
    }

    public ArrayList getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }

    public void setSeat(ArrayList seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }

    public ArrayList getMainClass() {
        return mainClass;
    }

    public void setMainClass(ArrayList mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    public ArrayList getAdultPrice() {
        return adultPrice;
    }

    public void setAdultPrice(ArrayList adultPrice) {
        this.adultPrice = adultPrice;
    }

    public ArrayList getChildPrice() {
        return childPrice;
    }

    public void setChildPrice(ArrayList childPrice) {
        this.childPrice = childPrice;
    }

    public ArrayList getInfantPrice() {
        return infantPrice;
    }

    public void setInfantPrice(ArrayList infantPrice) {
        this.infantPrice = infantPrice;
    }
}
```

I'm really confused to insert this data into listview because I use ListFragment. Maybe you can give a solution?

Comment: What have you tried else than this ? Are you assigning your work to some else here?

Comment: You have all the data now just try to bind it using custom adapter. And then ask for solution if you face any problem.

Comment: I ask because i confused now. I already try bind it into custom adapter, and i stuck. I already try to ask my friend, but she didn't know how to implement it too.

Comment: @Ketan I got error on 
12-24 17:36:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(5973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
did I use wrong extends or use the id attribute wrong?

Comment: if your activity extends `ListActivity` then in xml use listview id as `android:id="@id/list` otherwise `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: I'm using Fragment not Activity or ListActivity. Btw I solved it now. I change the ListFragment into Fragment, and It shows the data I want.